# Android App Widget, variables are restarting

Tags: java, android, service, widget

I have been developing a widget for an application and I keep having problems, if I close the application the widget restarts all his values and stays working. How can I keep the values of my widget? I´m using a service to read a XML file and put the information on variables that are restarting to his default value if i close my application. I call the service from the onUpdate of the widget.

Answer (score 2):

Use `SharedPreferences`. These let you save your settings and persistent values to the device's storage.

To do so, you can do something like this to load settings:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("SETTINGS", 0);
int x = prefs.getInt("x", 5); // Pulls an integer with key "x", defaulting to 5 if it's not set
String y = prefs.getString("y", null); // Pulls an string with key "y", defaulting to null if it's not set
```

And you can save settings like this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("SETTINGS", 0);
Editor edit = prefs.edit();
edit.putInt("x", 27);
edit.putString("y", "Some string");
edit.commit();
```

*Note: I called the items `SETTINGS` here, but any basic type of data, which you wish to load again later, can be stored (`String`, `int`, `float`, etc.).*

You may want to read the documentation on [storage options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) and [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).